# Get the selected dropdown item and display in the console log

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

i wanted to get the selected value the i select in my dropdown. however whenever i put event.target it returns undefined in my function. can someone help me. Thank you

This is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-golick-if0nf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What you are looking for is Select component . The Dropdown component provided by bloomer is not suitable for this case . I don't see any onChange prop being provided by the API to capture the selected value .

Comment: Adding to Shyam's point, even if it had onChange method, you are calling it in wrong way. This is the reason it is printing undefined because `filterData` get's called when the Dropdown component is being rendered.


`onChange={(e)=>filterData(e)}}` This is the right way